# Magnify Y axis in Java Mission Control charts

Tags: java, graph, jmc, java-mission-control, jfr

I recently recorded a Java Flight Recorder (JFR) dump of a java program. When I opened it using Java Mission Control (JMC), I could adjust the X axis but not Y (In many graphs). I tried flipping my screen (ctrl + alt + arrow key) and it worked ;-) However, I need a more suitable method to do this.

All I need is to get a bigger graph of JFR dump's CPU usage. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can use the Designer view to remove the rest of the UI from the partical tab you are looking at: Window/Show View/Designer, then navigate to the tab you want, click the red stop button in the Designer view, right-click the UI parts you want to remove. To get the UI back into normal state, go into Window/Preferences, Java Mission Control/Flight Recorder, Reset UI Interface. You can also use the Designer view to create your own tab with just the CPU chart, if you want that.

Comment: Thanks @Klara. :-) That was exactly what I wanted.